# Отображение картинки справа налево при rtl ориентации

Tags: android, gui

Возможно ли как-нибудь отобразить картинку зеркально при правосторонней ориентации (нужно для арабской локализации)?

Например есть чат `Я`/`КТО-ТО`, в котором на бэкграунде моих сообщений нижний **левый угол** подогнут. При смене ориентации на правостороннюю, мои сообщения начинают появляться **справа**, но по прежнему подогнут **левый угол**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете задать разные ресурсы-картинки для разных локалей или отразить картинку программно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7925903/3212712):

```
BitmapDrawable flip(BitmapDrawable d)
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.preScale(-1, 1);
    Bitmap src = d.getBitmap();
    Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), m, false);
    dst.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return new BitmapDrawable(dst);
}
```